# SoftEther Authentication "Access denied"

Tags: c#, .net, api, server, vpn

I'm using [SoftEther APIs](https://github.com/hoppler/SoftEtherApi) to connect to a VPS and then try to build a VPN on that .
I can successfully connect to server using IP and Port, then at Authentication step I get "Access denied" and no more details.
The authentication step is using Password and HubName.

I've read the APIs codes deeply and I realized it using `SHA0` algorithm to encrypt password and take a random arrays of bytes from server and use that as salt in encrypt method . 
So I've changed the encryption method at SoftEther Application to `AES128` , `AES256` and some others but the result has not been changed at all. 
I also tried to send password as  an `ASCII` but none of them worked.

The exact API code without change:

```
using (var softEther = new SoftEther(ip, port))
{    
    // the connection step that would pass successfully :           
    var connectResult = softEther.Connect();
    if (!connectResult.Valid())
    {                    
        Console.WriteLine(connectResult.Error);
        return;
    }         

// the Authentication step that got problem :            
    var authResult = softEther.Authenticate(pw, hubName);
    if (!authResult.Valid())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(authResult.Error);
        return;
    }

    // the code stops and don't get here :           
    var user = softEther.HubApi.GetUser(hubName, userName);
    Console.WriteLine(user.Valid() ? "Success" : 
    user.Error.ToString()); 
}
```

And this is the [authResult](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VrqHXwX5qMwKoLC-kaIdRRYvbTeAYiB-) I get

Comment: some how , I just figured out what should I do . these APIs are for handling the Admin panel . For instance : create user , monitor server traffic and etc . I was trying to connect by a client's username and password. for that part , I've to use something link [VpnClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/vpnclient/?view=win10-ps)

Answer (score 0):

Well since you are working on server side of SoftEther i would **recommend** you to use VPNCMD for managing or retrieving info from SoftEther server.

VPNCMD Virtual Hub commands:
https://www.softether.org/4-docs/1-manual/6._Command_Line_Management_Utility_Manual/6.4_VPN_Server_%2F%2F_VPN_Bridge_Management_Command_Reference_(For_Virtual_Hub)

For example enter the following in cmd/terminal:

> vpncmd /server {serverIP} /PASSWORD:{server password}
>   /adminhub:{server HUB Name} /CMD UserCreate {username}
>   /GROUP:{groupname} /REALNAME:{user fullname} /NOTE:{anything}

Requirements:
Download and install SoftEther server manager for your machine OS(ie from where you want to control remote server)

You can also execute VPN Client functions from VPNCMD:https://www.softether.org/4-docs/1-manual/6._Command_Line_Management_Utility_Manual/6.5_VPN_Client_Management_Command_Reference

Comment: whoever disliked the answer.... this is a request to comment the reason for disliking...